# Circular Dependencies in RESTful API with Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, api, spring-boot

I'm developing a Rest API using Spring Boot, JPA with Hibernate and Maven as repository manager. In my Model I have the class `Club`:

```js
@Entity
@Table( name = "CLUB")
public class Club {

   /**
    * Id da entidade
    */
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

    /**
    * Atual técnico do clube.
    */
   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "actualClub")
   private Coach coach;
   
   //Outros atributos, getters e setters
  }
```

The above class has a `@OneToOne` relationship with the class `Coach`:

```js
@Entity
@Table(name = "COACH")
public class Coach extends Person {

   /**
    * Clube atual do técnico.
    */
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "CLUB_ID")
   private Club actualClub;

   //Outros atributos, getters e setters
   
}
```

The class `Person` also has an attribute **id** with `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue` annotations.

Lastly, I also have the controller class `ClubController`, which handle some requests, as you can see below:

```js
@RestController
public class ClubController {

   /**
    * Instância da classe de serviços da entidade <i>Club</i>
    */
   @Autowired
   private ClubService clubService;

   /**
    * Retorna JSON que representa o clube com o 'id' especificado.
    *
    * @param id Identificador do clube a ser buscado.
    * @return ResponseEntity Objeto com detalhes da requisição HTTP, como o Status.
    */
   @RequestMapping(value = "/clubs/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
           method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<?> getClubById(@PathVariable Long id) {

      final Club club = this.clubService.findById(id);
      if (club != null) {
         return new ResponseEntity<>(club, HttpStatus.FOUND);
      } else {
         return new ResponseEntity<>("Não encontrado", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
      }
   }
   
   /*Entre outros métodos...*/
   
}
```

The problem is: in a `GET` in `/clubs/{id}` the returned JSON has a circular (infinite) dependency inside it. Club has a Coach which has a Club and and so it goes... X(
This will also happen with the `@OneToMany relationship between`Club`and`Player`...

I've found this solution: [Link](https://dzone.com/articles/circular-dependencies-jackson). I just have to use the `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation in the class declaration. The problem with this solution is the overhead of information that I won't use (Just think in `@OneToMany` relationship with `Player`). Besides, as you can see in the above link:

> "However, JSON id references need to be unique across the entire graph, whereas JPA id’s only need to be unique within the same entity.""

So, I'll have to use UUID’s for JPA id fields.

I've also found another possible solution: [Spring HATEOAS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/). In this case, I could add links (href) to some attributes and just would make the requisition *"on demand"*. But seems that Spring HATEOAS has some limitations, like support for embedding resource...

So, which approach should I follow? Are there other solutions?

Soon enough, I intend to use this API in an iOS app (I don't know if it makes difference).

*Sorry about my poor English... Greetings from Brazil x)*

Comment: The second approach looks like the Spotify Web API [link](https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/0sNOF9WDwhWunNAHPD3Baj/tracks?offset=0&limit=50) . Each album has a href link to its tracks.

Comment: Just for the case, this concerns me: [Why I Hate HATEOAS](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/03/why-i-hate-hateoas/)

Comment: To resolve the circular reference,you should break the link of two object.You can see annotation JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate both relationships with `@JsonIgnoreProperties`

as follows

```
// Employee entity, owning side of relationship 
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("employee")
private Department department;

// Department side, inverse side of relationship
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("department")
private Collection<Employee> employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved creating your own DTO (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)

A data transfer object (DTO) is a Java structure created just to organize data for transfer to another system. It's created as needed, with no irrelevant or private information, and no circular references.

For example:

```
private Map<String, Object> makeClubDTO(Club club) {
  Map<String, Object> dto = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
  dto.put("id", club.getId());
  dto.put("coach", club.getCoach().getId());
  return dto;
}
```

Comment: It works for me. It sounds like a good idea. Just for referente: [Entity To DTO Conversion for a Spring REST API](http://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application).